# laravel 8 and Laravel-dompdf via API

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js, dompdf

is there a way to generate a pdf file from controller to vue js component via api route??

```
public function usersPrintPdf()
    {
        $data = [
            'title' => 'First PDF for Medium',
            'heading' => 'Hello from 99Points.info',
            'content' => 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text remaining essentially unchanged.'
        ];

        $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdfs/pdf_view', $data);
        return $pdf->download('users.pdf');
    }
```

and on api.php

```
Route::get('users/print-pdf', [UserController::class, 'usersPrintPdf']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [vue-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-pdf) library to show pdf in vue

**Example - basic**

**Note:** Replace `src="#"` with a route that calls `/users/print-pdf` api route.

```js
<template>
  <pdf src="#"></pdf>
</template>

<script>
import pdf from 'vue-pdf'

export default {
  components: {
    pdf
  }
}
```